# maximum contrast using linear gery-level trasformation

Tags: image-processing

this was a question i found online.

given an image with values between [0,1].
how can I get the maximum contrast using linear gray-level transformation? 
something like I(x,y)=A*I(x,y)+B , where I is a histogram.
we are also given MAX(I) and MIN(I).

as far as i can understand. 
MAX(I) and MIN(I) will give you the values you have now and you wan to stretch the values into 0 and 1.

but how will this give me a linear equation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to design a linear transformation, that puts the MIN(I) at 0 and the MAX(I) at 1. A linear equation has the form: `y = m*x+b`, where `m` is the slope and `b` is the point on the y-axis for `x = 0`.

You want to choose `m` such that it goes from 0 to 1 (`dy = y_max - y_min = 1 - 0 = 1`) within the interval from MIN(I) to MAX(I) (`dx = x_max - x_min = MAX(I) - MIN(I)`):

```
m = 1/(MAX(I)-MIN(I));
```

Next you want to make sure, that `y = m * MIN(I) + b == 0`:

```
b = -m*MIN(I);
```

If you have any further questions, let me know.

Comment: let's say i want to double the image contrast. what will i need to do then. just add a bigger b?

Comment: I suggest, that you open a photograph (convert into grayscale if needed) in GIMP (www.gimp.org) and play around with the "Colors -> Curves" menu item. This way you can see the effects immediately. In order to increase the contrast, you have to increase the slope (`m`) and adjust `b` accordingly. Now some values will need to be clipped to the allowed interval [0;1].

Answer (score 3):

If you're subtracting the minimum and stretching the maximum remaining value to be 1, you get the following:

Let $m = \min\{I(x,y)\}$ and $M = \max\{I(x,y)\}$
$$I_{\text{new}}(x,y) = \frac{I(x,y) - m}{M-m} = AI(x,y)+B $$

where $A=\dfrac{1}{M-m}$ and $B = -\dfrac{m}{M-m}$

Hope this clears it up.